# Why Getting SunCertPathBuilderException at Starting of Content in Spring Tool Suite 4?

Tags: networking, certificate, spring-tool-suite

I'm working in a company network and was trying to import a "Spring Getting Started Content" (File -> New -> Spring Getting Started Content). The wizard open, but in both categories (Getting Started Guide, Reference App) is the error "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" shown.

I already included our company certificate and the spring.io - certificate to my cacerts of my used jre. Additional i set the proxy settings for our company proxy server (Window -> Preferences -> Network -> Manual).

If I try to add a Cloud Foundry Target, I also need to authentificate. The same error occours. But here I have the option to "Skip SSL Validation" and then it works.

I expect it to work after I included the spring.io certificate, but maybe the download request ist against something else?

I also added a github cert.

Comment: The getting started guides don't come from spring.io but from github. Does adding a ca certifcate for that help? If not, maybe you have to have a conversation with your IT department and ask them if there's anything they can do to allow you to do your work without constantly fighting the network setup.

Comment: @Kris updated the question and my settings, but the problem is still there

Comment: I am getting the same error. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: no. sadly not @neil